# Adding 3rd party custom library in Yii2

Tags: yii2, avalara

I have a tax library avalara. How can I add it using Yii2. I have tried in putting in Vendor folder. 
used

> require "/vendor/avalara/avalara.php"

it does include the file does wasn't able to call the functions inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the avalara library. Extract the file and put the AvaTax and autoload foler in vendor.
Add the a class file in model directory.

> $base_path = str_replace("frontend", "", \Yii::$app->basePath);
>
> require_once $base_path . 'vendor/avalara/vendor/autoload.php';
>
> use Yii;
>
> use AvaTax\Address;
>
> use AvaTax\DetailLevel;
>
> use AvaTax\GetTaxRequest;
>
> use AvaTax\Line;
>
> use AvaTax\TaxServiceSoap;
>
> use AvaTax\ATConfig;
>
> use AvaTax\CancelTaxRequest;

After that create custom functions and use them in controller.